# How many catastrophic shoe failures occur in college basketball?

Tags: basketball, equipment

I don't watch a lot of basketball, but I did see a game yesterday where the player's shoe tore wide open.

In sports, equipment failure is certainly part of the game but in US college sports (which is typically well-funded, meaning they don't need to play using substandard equipment) I have never before seen a shoe failure such as this.

Have there been other cases in college or professional basketball where shoes have failed in this manner?

[image: broken shoe]

Comment: https://ftw.usatoday.com/2019/02/zion-williamson-nike-shoe-history

Comment: USA today was able to find a few clips of failures, I see.  Half were not the same type of failure since one was caused by pulling from under another player's foot and another was a sole coming off.  Two were similar failures.  8 years worth of games and so few documented failures.  And commentators saying "I've never seen that before".

Comment: For what it's worth - before I got old I was squatting 650.   I was pretty skinny to be squatting that so it was a rotate and press hard movement.   I could blow out a pair of Nike running shoes (air pockets deflate) every 3-4 sessions.  No hole or puncture just no air and not really sure I could tell when it happened but it was repeatable.   Nike sent me a couple of replacements when I complained.   A side note is if you have blown out air pockets terrible for running/sports but super comfy - like slippers.

Answer (score 1):

## Yes, there have been.

From 2010 to 2014 there have been approximately 10 NBA sneaker mishaps.
https://www.complex.com/sneakers/2014/04/history-of-sneaker-mishaps-in-the-nba/tony-wroten-loses-sole-of-his-jordan-x

This is an uncommon occurance, but in the NBA, it seems to happen about 2 times every season. If a shoe just falls off someone's foot, they keep on playing. The link above shows a history of sneaker mishaps from 2010 to 2014